# What approach to a post based (like a blog) webpage, with separate page to allow users to add a post

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, blogs

I'm currently trying to develop my own website from scratch as I try and teach myself more about web development. I'd like to work out how to have a section on my website that displays blog posts I write, but without having to edit the HTML each time I write a post. I'd like a separate page where someone can write a blog, then when they press submit, it will add it to the website.

I've had a nose about online and a think about it. I'm guessing this is like a content management system, but I'm unsure if this is something I should try and manually code myself or if there's common practice out there for this sort of thing.

My thoughts on how to tackle the problem would be as follows. I'm guessing blog posts will need to be stored in a database. On the page that displays blog posts, it won't contain hard coding of any blog posts, but instead they will be pulled from a database and displayed. So you'd need to write code that will extract records from a database and display the heading / content as you desire, with a separator between posts. And you limit maybe to fetching X amount of posts from the database at a time. Then with regards to the writing of posts, I'd need to make a webpage that you log in to, and write a blog post as if it was a form and submit it to the database via Php or something? I appreciate this may not included a fancy text editor while writing a blog post, mind.

I'm sorry if this isn't the right type of question for stackoverflow. I know I've not presented code for you to help with, but it is about how these things are coded - so I don't start working on something redundant. Thanks for reading.

(FYI: My experiences so far are creating a website that uses HTML, CSS and a small amount of Javascript, using PHP and MYSQL. I've created a log in system, and allowed users to add, edit and delete records via forms. I've displayed information from databases in forms and tables.)

Comment: That is more or less how this generally works, yes. But as a beginner you might be better off using an existing, established system, than writing your own - especially the security aspects of the whole thing are usually harder to grasp for beginners.

Comment: If I was to try and do this myself adding to a database using forms etc though, do you think it would be useful / constructive towards becoming better at this? My goal isn't to create a website, but to become a web developer. Also, when you say using an established system - do they give you code that you embed into your html? or do the blogs get hosted on some other system and just displayed on your website?

Comment: Learning by doing is definitively a good thing, yes. But if you start with something rather complex like this, chances are you might get lost by the sheer amount of stuff you need to know/learn; so I would rather start a little smaller, resp. break this down into several steps. Like for your own tests, just to create new posts and to display the existing ones, you probably don’t need a login system right away ...

Comment: And the “established systems”, meaning popular blog software/CMS like f.e. WordPress, can come in two “flavors” - one where code and data is hosted by an external provider, and one where you install the whole system on your own server. Usually you do not just simply embed a little bit of code into your HTML to make this work; but rather the whole of your HTML is generated by the system, using _template files_.

Comment: Appreciate the time you've given to explain. I'll have a nose into template files and how to host word press on my own server sometime. For now I might go with the approach of adding to my own database, as the skill-set seems very similar to the skills I developed a previous project (where there was a login, and different users had ability to either view records, or also add/edit/delete).

Answer (score 0):

Store everything in database.

Simple way (you can make it complicated later),
table structure:

```
    MainTable

    text_id(Primary Key), 
    used_id(Foreign Key), 
    approved(allowed to be displayed), 
    text(text body)
```

User(You) with access to admin panel.
Admin Panel page to approve texts to be displayed.

```
    select * from MainTable WHERE approved = 0
```

You have all unapproved texts.

```
    UPDATE MainTable SET approved = 1 WHERE text_id = /this text id/
```

Now it can be displayed.

Page where you want display texts.

You would have to identify user with user_id to get his texts.

```
    SELECT * from MainTable WHERE user_id = /this user id/ and apporoved = 1
```

display texts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. It is helpful just to hear others views, as I wasn't sure if my thoughts about it were too basic or if there was a "preferred way" people dealt with this problem. Seems what you said is similar in terms of logic to the way I'd have gone about it :)